# How to divide a DocumentFragment based on character offset

Tags: javascript, html, dom, documentfragment

I have a string that (potentially) contains HTML tags.

I want to split it into smaller valid HTML strings based on (text) character length. The use case is essentially pagination. I know the length of text that can fit on a single page. So I want to divide the target string into "chunks" or pages based on that character length. But I need each of the resulting pages to contain valid HTML without unclosed tags, etc.

So for example:

```
const pageCharacterSize = 10
const testString = 'some <strong>text with HTML</strong> tags
function paginate(string, pageSize) { //@TODO }
const pages = paginate(testString, pageCharacterSize)
console.log(pages)
// ['some <strong>text </strong>', '<strong>with HTML</strong> ', 'tags']
```

I think this is possible to do with a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) or [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) but I can't figure out how slice the pages based on character offsets.

[This MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretPositionFromPoint#examples) has a demo that does something close to what I need. But it uses `caretPositionFromPoint()` which takes `X`, `Y` coordinates as arguments.

**Update**

For the purposes of clarity, here are the tests I'm working with:

```js
import { expect, test } from 'vitest'
import paginate from './paginate'

// 1
test('it should chunk plain text', () => {
  // a
  const testString = 'aa bb cc dd ee';
  const expected = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee']
  expect(paginate(testString, 2)).toStrictEqual(expected)

  // b
  const testString2 = 'a a b b c c';
  const expected2 = ['a a', 'b b', 'c c']
  expect(paginate(testString2, 3)).toStrictEqual(expected2)

  // c
  const testString3 = 'aa aa bb bb cc cc';
  const expected3 = ['aa aa', 'bb bb', 'cc cc']
  expect(paginate(testString3, 5)).toStrictEqual(expected3)
  
  // d
  const testString4 = 'aa bb cc';
  const expected4 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
  expect(paginate(testString4, 4)).toStrictEqual(expected4)

  // e
  const testString5 = 'a b c d e f g';
  const expected5 = ['a b c', 'd e f', 'g']
  expect(paginate(testString5, 5)).toStrictEqual(expected5)

  // f
  const testString6 = 'aa bb cc';
  const expected6 = ['aa bb', 'cc']
  expect(paginate(testString6, 7)).toStrictEqual(expected6)
})

// 2
test('it should chunk an HTML string without stranding tags', () => {
  const testString = 'aa <strong>bb</strong> <em>cc dd</em>';
  const expected = ['aa', '<strong>bb</strong>', '<em>cc</em>', '<em>dd</em>']
  expect(paginate(testString, 3)).toStrictEqual(expected)
})

// 3
test('it should handle tags that straddle pages', () => {
  const testString = '<strong>aa bb cc</strong>';
  const expected = ['<strong>aa</strong>', '<strong>bb</strong>', '<strong>cc</strong>']
  expect(paginate(testString, 2)).toStrictEqual(expected)
})
```

Comment: This can be tricky, the devil is in the details. What if there is a big HTML table or div that spans multiple pages? What if there are embedded images or other objects? It seems like you'd need to create an object in the DOM, then do the page split based on actual space used. If you use a regex you can't asses actual space used of the rendered HTML.

Comment: Good point. My strings will only have inline tags. But your idea about basing it on the page  spave is interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that assumes and supports the following:

- tags without attributes (you could tweak the regex to support that)
- well formed tags assumed, e.g. not: `<b><i>wrong nesting</b></i>`, `missing <b>end tag`, `missing start</b> tag`
- tags may be nested
- tags are removed & later restored for proper characters per page count
- page split is done by looking backwards for first space

```js
function paginate(html, pageSize) {
  let splitRegex = new RegExp('\\s*[\\s\\S]{1,' + pageSize + '}(?!\\S)', 'g');
  let tagsInfo = [];  // saved tags
  let tagOffset = 0;  // running offset of tag in plain text
  let pageOffset = 0; // page offset in plain text
  let openTags = [];  // open tags carried over to next page
  let pages = html.replace(/<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/gi, (tag, pos) => {
    let obj = { tag: tag, pos: pos - tagOffset };
    tagsInfo.push(obj);
    tagOffset += tag.length;
    return '';
  }).match(splitRegex).map(page => {
    let nextOffset = pageOffset + page.length;
    let prefix = openTags.join('');
    tagsInfo.slice().reverse().forEach(obj => {
      if(obj.pos >= pageOffset && obj.pos < nextOffset) {
        // restore tags in reverse order to maintain proper position
        page = page.substring(0, obj.pos - pageOffset) + obj.tag + page.substring(obj.pos - pageOffset);
      }
    });
    tagsInfo.forEach(obj => {
      let tag = obj.tag;
      if(obj.pos >= pageOffset && obj.pos < nextOffset) {
        if(tag.match(/<\//)) {
          // remove tag from openTags list
          tag = tag.replace(/<\//, '<');
          let index = openTags.indexOf(tag);
          if(index >= 0) {
            openTags.splice(index, 1);
          }
        } else {
          // add tag to openTags list
          openTags.push(tag);
        }
      }
    });
    pageOffset = nextOffset;
    let postfix = openTags.slice().reverse().map(tag => tag.replace(/</, '</')).join('');
    page = prefix + page.trim() + postfix;
    return page.replace(/<(\w+)><\/\1>/g, ''); // remove tags with empty content
  });
  return pages;
}

[
  { str: 'some <strong>text <i>with</i> HTML</strong> tags, and <i>some <b>nested tags</b> sould be <b>supported</b> as well</i>.', size: 16 },
  { str: 'a a b b c c', size: 3 },
  { str: 'aa aa bb bb cc cc', size: 5 },
  { str: 'aa bb cc', size: 4 },
  { str: 'aa <strong>bb</strong> <em>cc dd</em>', size: 3 },
  { str: '<strong>aa bb cc</strong>', size: 2 }
].forEach(o => {
  let pages = paginate(o.str, o.size);
  console.log(pages);
});
```

Output:

```
[
  "some <strong>text <i>with</i></strong>",
  "<strong> HTML</strong> tags, and",
  "<i>some <b>nested tags</b></i>",
  "<i> sould be</i>",
  "<i><b>supported</b> as</i>",
  "<i>well</i>."
]
[
  "a a",
  "b b",
  "c c"
]
[
  "aa aa",
  "bb bb",
  "cc cc"
]
[
  "aa",
  "bb",
  "cc"
]
[
  "aa",
  "<strong>bb</strong>",
  " <em>cc</em>",
  "<em>dd</em>"
]
[
  "<strong>aa</strong>",
  "<strong>bb</strong>",
  "<strong>cc</strong>"
]
```

**Update**

Based on new request in comment I fixed the split regex from `'[\\s\\S]{1,' + pageSize + '}(?!\\S)'` to `'\\s*[\\s\\S]{1,' + pageSize + '}(?!\\S)'`, e.g. added `\\s*` to catch leading spaces. I also added a `page.trim()` to remove leading spaces. Finally I added a few of the OP examples.

Comment: This is great work! I'm still studying the code to understand it all, but there's one main "bug" that I'm seeing. It's handling white-space in a way that's not quite right for pagination. Ex: `const testString = 'a a b b c c';
  const expected = ['a a', 'b b', 'c c'];
  expect(paginate(testString, 3)).toStrictEqual(expected);` When I run your code I'm getting: `["a a","b","b","c","c"]`. Is this any easy fix?

Comment: In case it's more clear, I added a snippet to the question with all my tests. Thanks again for your interest in this question!

Comment: I updated the splitRegex to `'(?<!\\S)[\\s\\S]{1,' + pageSize + '}(?!\\S)'` and this allows test 1 to pass. But now test 2 is failing with `["aa", "b<strong>b</strong>", "<strong>c</strong>c", "<em>dd</em>"]`. I think my regex is excluding the leading spaces, which throws off the tag offset...

Comment: This gets it done! `splitRegex = new RegExp('\\s?\\S[\\s\\S]{0,' + pageSizeMinusOne + '}(?!\\S)', 'g')`. Explanation (for anyone that cares): my modification of the RegEx includes the leading space in the match, but NOT in the page size calculation. In this approach, all characters need to be matched in order for the subsequent offsets to line up correctly. But excluding it from the quantifier means it won't count towards the page size, and can be `trim()`ed off later.